# Docker telemetry and performance monitoring

Tags: docker, monitoring, telemetry

What will telemetry and monitoring tools show if I lunch in (2 options)

- docker container
- host system

Will they show cpu\memory and etc usage of container only or of host system?

What are best practise? Monitoring software in each container or in host system?

Comment: Have a look to [Google Cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results should be exactly the same, because Docker containers are sharing their resources (unlike virtual machines).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is monitor both, the host(s) and the containers running on them.  A good way to do that is run a container that collects all data on each docker host.  That is how [Sematext Docker Agent](https://github.com/sematext/sematext-agent-docker) runs, for example -- it runs as a tiny container on each Docker host and collects all host+containers metrics, events, and logs.  It then parses logs, can route them, blacklist/whitelist them, auto-discovery new containers, and so on.  In the end logs end up in [Logsene](http://sematext.com/logsene) and metrics and events end up in [SPM](http://sematext.com/spm), which gives you a single pane of glass sort of view into all your Docker ops bits, with alerting, anomaly detection, correlation, and so on. I hope this helps and points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an agent in your containers is not advisable, not just for performance reasons, but it is an anti-pattern in the Docker world, where each container should run a single process. Better is to run a monitoring agent on the host or in a separate container that can be configured to extract metrics from the other containers. This is the way we work at CoScale. If you are interested, have a look at our solution for [monitoring Docker](http://www.coscale.com/docker-monitoring).